# handling more than 1500 divs for zooming and dragging?

Tags: jquery, html, animation, web, svg

I am trying to make a small app to draw a garden with svg graphics where i can drag and pan around.
here is a demo: http://pmtesting1.meteor.com/ (click for drag and scroll for zoom)
the demo shows a big svg element with about 1400 node in it.

maybe there is a better solution? 
or some tips would be nice!

the only thing is: the plants should be svg images.

Thx for your help and tipps !

What i tried: to put every plant into one svg and group this helped a little bit but it still lags.
I tried to make many svg elements and this was a disaster.

Comment: This reminds me of a similar-looking game http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centipede_(video_game)

Comment: haha your right! a little bit ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should only load/draw the element's which are currently in view and so will get rendered. If you manage to only pass that elements, you could (theoretically) have unlimited elements ..

If you really want to go deep in performance tuning, I would suggest a quadtree, but that's maybe a bit too much for a simple application.

Maybe that link: [how many stacked canvas elements is too much](http://mcgivery.com/how-many-stacked-canvas-elements-is-too-much/) helps to get a general overview of canvas performance.

**Edit:** How you could do it:

- Make a list of elements, including their position. Compare each position, and when it's on screen, display it, else hide it. This would be the slow variant.
- You could also pack a bunch of elements which are close to each other in one chunk, and compare only the chunks. This will be a lot faster (to compare, not to render)
- Use a quadtree/bintree and perform frustrum culling. This requires a lot of work in javascript, but would be probably the fastest solution.

I am pretty sure there are api's which do the most work for you.

Comment: do you have any tips of how to get only the things rendered which are in view?